# Find Data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on my [Stretchbox Plugin](http://www.janiklipke.com/stretchbox) and trying to optimize and shorten the code.
I've used the jquery data method to attach data to certain divs.
For instance:

```
$('#thumbs div:last-child').data('active', true)
```

which sets a certain div to the active state.
If i know want to find this div, i have to check each .thumb class
in order to find it:

```
$('.thumb').each(function() {
    if($(this).data('active')){
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I'm quite sure there should be a much easier way, since checking up every single .thumb  div(out of 10-30) will take some performance too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no other way to do it. You could, however, create a new jQuery selector. I was going to give it a shot, but it looks like [someone has already thought of it](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/) (scroll down to "Querying element data").

It will allow you to do things like this:

```
$(':data(active)'); //Selects all elements with "active" data
```

It probably won't be faster, but it might make your code neater!

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector/2895933#2895933) is a much better and broader selector. :)

Comment: Nice find! I just linked to the first one I found and didn't look any further!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".thumb[data-active='true']");
```

Comment: Data which is set with `$.data()` [will not be available to the attribute selector](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/unALg/).

Comment: I actually had no clue that you can't select attributes set with $.data. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll leave the answer so others at least know what's wrong (upvote is meaningless too).

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something?  Just save it in a variable:

```
jQuery(function($){
  var activeDiv = [];

  $('#selector').click(function(){
    activeDiv = $('#thumbs div:last-child')
    ...
  });

  $('#executor').click(function() {
    activeDiv.each(function() {
        ...
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This is of course working but as I already mentioned I intended to use the data method, since I'm using it for other functions too and therefore was looking for a quicker way of doing it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Janik: I'm afraid that's a bit like saying that you prefer using a hammer to drive screws.  The data method is used to attach data to a DOM element for later retrieval by a plugin.  It can't speed up a DOM search.

Comment: Ok, thought it might be a another good way of doing it. Thanks for the hint.