# Placing content at end of data elements - how to select for that with data elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following markup and want to place 'here is my info' after this when an ajax callback is triggered. My markup:

```
<div data-item-header-id="17">
here is an item
</div>
<div data-item-header-id="17">
here is another item
</div>
<!-- put 'here is my info here' here -->
<div data-item-header-id="18">
here is another item
</div>
```

The alert is called but isn't being put in the right place. How would I select given the above markup?

```
if(r.is_placed_at_end=='true'){
  alert('will place at end');
  $('data(item-header-id==17):last)').after("here is my info");
}
```

I tried looking at this but didn't get me all the way there. [jquery data selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector)

Also, is this proper usage of data elements?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an attribute selector.

```
$('div[data-item-header-id="17"]:last').after("here is my info");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CcA3D/

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/