# jQuery Select # id with word as prefix and counter as suffix

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to select all id's with jQuery with a prefix "my" and a suffix "0-9".
Something like these $("#my$1-4") or is it just possible with a loop ?

```
    <div id="my1"/>
    <div id="my2"/>
    <div id="my3"/>
    <div id="my4"/>
    <div id="my5"/>
```

Comment: Do you need only **id** selector? Why not to use class, name or data selector.
For last one see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector

Also there are attributes selectors like this one http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First thoughts, which seems to work well:

```
$('div[id^="my"]').filter(
    function(){
        return this.id.match(/\d+$/);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9QL8y/).

The above selects all `div` elements whose `id` starts with the value `my`, and then filters the returned elements to those whose `id` *also* ends with numeric characters.

References:

- [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [Regular Expressions, at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: here's the spec https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-substrings Substring matching attribute selectors

Answer (score 4):

The prefix part is easily achievable with an [attribute starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$("div[id^=my]");
```

But there is no selector that will allow you to specify a range of characters, so a loop will have to be involved. I would suggest [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("div").filter(function () {
    return /^my\d$/.test(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have millions of elements that start with "my", you could do:

```
$('[id^=my]').filter(function() { return this.id.matches(/\d/) && this.id.length == 3 })
```

This grabs all elements that have an id starting with "my", contain a number, and are only 3 characters long (so "my54" will not match but "my6" will)