# How select elements using jquery based on its id suffix and prefix?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I would like to select elements with this id pattern:

```
<div id="prefix_0_sufix"></div>
<div id="prefix_1_sufix"></div>
<div id="prefix_2_sufix"></div>
... and so on ...
```

How can I get those elements with jquery selectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the 'attribute starts with' and 'attribute ends with' selectors:

```
$('div[id^="prefix_"][id$="_sufix"]');
```

You should note however, that it would be much more semantic and faster to use a common class. If you need to store data with the element, use a `data` attribute on the element instead.

```
<div class="foo" data-bar="0"></div>
<div class="foo" data-bar="1"></div>
<div class="foo" data-bar="2"></div>
```

From there you can use `filter()` to get a specific element from the set:

```
var $secondDiv = $('.foo').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('bar') == 1;
});
```

Or if the elements are ordinal, you could just use their index and not add the `data` attribute at all:

```
var $secondDiv = $('.foo:eq(1)');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div[id^="prefix"]').filter(
    function(){
        return this.id.match('suffix');
    }).css('background-color','#0f0');
```

[jQuery Select # id with word as prefix and counter as suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173188/jquery-select-id-with-word-as-prefix-and-counter-as-suffix)

Comment: Note that `^=` is 'starts with'.