# Select JQuery elements that have some value set by data()

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery data selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector)

I have several elements with class 'connection_name'.  Each one of these elements has a unique id bound to it using the data() JQuery function.  I'm trying to query to find the element with a given id, but I can't seem to get it to work.

For the sake of this test, I created a page with only 1 element, and set the id of the element.

I can verify that the id is being set, as when I query the element in the console, it shows the id returned:

```
$('.connection_name').data()
  Object
  id: "4fea76bd99ea080d19000002"
  __proto__: Object
```

I've read on other questsions/posts that the element should be selected by $('selector[data-attribute=value]'), but that doesn't seem to work:

```
$('.connection_name[data-id="4fea76bd99ea080d19000002"]')
[]
```

Worse than that, even when I try to select it without any value (just by the attribute), I still return nothing:

```
$('.connection_name[data-id]')
[]
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, or how to go about doing this.

Comment: That link has a perfect answer (if @jfriend00's answer isn't good enough)

Comment: @Thomas, actually the link you provided doesn't help at all.  On that answer, they suggest $('selector[data-attribute=value]') will work and it doesn't, hence my question.

Comment: The answer has a whole load of code to get that to work. Read the accepted answer.

Comment: No, it really doesn't.  It's not an adequate answer at all.  Jfriend provided a much clearer, better answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var theItem = $('.connection_name').filter(function() {
    return($(this).data("id") === "4fea76bd99ea080d19000002");
});
```

Comment: This works well, thanks jfriend.  Do you happen to know why the $('selector[data-attribute=value]') pattern doesn't work?  Several sources seem to claim that it does.  Thanks again.

Comment: They're two different things. If you set data-* attributes on the elements, jQuery reads them ONCE, at document ready, and syncs them to its internal data storage. If you update these values later, using `.data()`, the attributes will not change. In the same way, if you update the data-* attributes using `.attr()`, the jQuery internal data storage will not change. So instead you have to iterate over every single element that fits your criteria, and read its data.

Comment: @RyanOgle - When you do an attribute selector, that ONLY reads  attributes from the actual DOM object, thus `'.connection_name[id="4fea76bd99ea080d19000002"]'` will only work if there is a data-id attribute on the object with that value.  This will only be the case if the attribute is present in the HTML or if it is set with `.attr()`.  If it the id value is set with `.data("id", "4fea76bd99ea080d19000002")`, then the value is NOT set as an attribute on the object (it's set in an internal data structure inside of jQuery) and thus it will not be found by a selector operation.