# How to check if there exists at least one li element with attr = something?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to check if there is any li element that has a attribute of "data-foo" and its value is "bar".

Would this work? :

```
if ($('li[data-foo=bar]'))
{
//exists
}
else
{
//does not exist
}
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery data selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector)

Comment: how is this a duplicate of what you referenced?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Get `length` of elements retured by selector if it is `greater` then `zero` then it means you have `atleast one` element with provided condition in selector.

```
if ($('li[data-foo=bar]').length > 0)
{
//exists
}
else
{
//does not exist
}
```