# How to find all elements that are not within a data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Using jQuery / Underscore, Given the following list. How can I find all `.msg` elements that are not within an li w `data-allow-html="true"`

```
<ol>
    <li><div class="msg">message</div></li>
    <li data-allow-html="true"><div class="msg">message</div></li>
    <li><div class="msg">message</div></li>
    <li data-allow-html="true"><div class="msg">message</div></li>
    <li><div class="msg">message</div></li>
    <li data-allow-html="true"><div class="msg">message</div></li>
    <li><div class="msg">message</div></li>
    <li data-allow-html="true"><div class="msg">message</div></li>
</ol>
```

I currently have:

```
$('#mydiv').find('.msg').each(function() {}
```

And have tried:

```
$('#mydiv').find('li').not('data-allow-html="true"').find('.msg').each(function() {}
```

Which does not seem to work. Ideas? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to get all the `<li>` withing `#mydiv`, then checking for `not()` containing the attribute, then finding each `.msg`

```
$('#mydiv li').not('[data-allow-html="true"]').find('.msg').each(function() {
    // your code
});​
```

Comment: the data is not in the same element as .msg but in the parent()

Answer (score 1):

In your **code this is** `not('data-allow-html="true"')`
supposed to be `not('[data-allow-html="true"]')`  .. // Missing **[]**

You can also try it this way

```
 $('li').not('[data-allow-html]').find('.msg').each(function() {

       $(this).css('color', 'orange')
        // Your code here
 });
```

//OR

```
$('li:not([data-allow-html])').find('.msg').each(function() {

});
```

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/wgXAB/)**