# Twitter bootstrap and dynamic dom elements

Tags: jquery, events, tooltip

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to create [tooltips](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips). Currently, I init the tooltips in `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

This calls `tooltip()` (which inits the listeners) for every element that has the `data-toggle` element.

The problem is that if I have dynamic DOM elements (using Ajax), the `tooltip()` will not be called on them. I thought of a solution like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('ready', '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', function() {
        $(this).tooltip();
    });
});
```

But that doesn't work..

Any ideas..?

Comment: What bout just executing `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` when new items are added?

Comment: Try to not use data as selectors. They are not meant for that, and they are slow to select. Use classes or ID instead. Also, if you set data attributes with `.data()`, your selectors won't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just re-init the plugin once your ajax method has returned (and the new elements have been injected):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.html',
    type: 'post',
    data: { foo: "bar"},
    success: function (html) {

        $("#foo").html(html);
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    }
});
```

Comment: $('#foo [data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  should be slight better