# jquery selector (":data(dialog)")

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I just googled how to check if an div is initialized as a dialog.

```
$(this).is(':data(dialog)');
```

I don't fully understand above code. 
Is this means that every initialized dialog has a variable "dialog" and it is set as true ? 
Is data() as selector here is the same as in $.data() function ? 
Any article should I read ?

Comment: Where did you find that?

Comment: Yes, when a dialog is created, the element has a `dialog` data value added to it.

Comment: http://old.nabble.com/How-can-you-check-if-a-dialog-has-been-initialised--td25538383s27240.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery data selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector)

Comment: Note to voters : the duplicate was confirmed after discussion in comments (see my answer).

Comment: After an update to jQuery-ui 1.11.2 the data key seems to have changed from 'dialog' to 'ui-dialog' so the above line should read: `$(this).is(':data(ui-dialog)');`

Answer (score 2):

This makes an error.

If there was a `:data` pseudo-selector it would test if it applies. And it would return a boolean but not change anything.

But there is no `:data` pseudo selector if you're not using a specific plugin. See [reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Note that some people *have* created such a pseudo-selector : [jquery data selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector)

But it's not standard and of course the result would depend on the plugin you use. In "vanilla jQuery", `$(this).is(':data(dialog)');` just makes an error.

Comment: <strike>There is a `:data` pseudo-selector.  `$.expr[':'].data`</strike> EDIT: I tested it on this page, which apparently uses a jQuery plugin to add it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Do you have a link ? When I test I have an "unsupported pseudo: data" error.

Comment: Weird.  I open a JS console on this page, and it worked.  I guess SO is using a plugin.

Comment: @dystroy More interested in the selector. So If I have `<div id='test'></div>`, how to make it selected ?

Comment: @dystroy No, I mean how to make the div returns true with `$(this).is(':data(dialog)');` line ?

Comment: @HendryH. look at the link I give in my answer. It points towards another question and proposed implementations.

Comment: If you confirm that's what you need, let's close this question as duplicate. OK ?

Comment: Answer to my own question, how to make `<div id='test'></div>` returns true for `$(this).is(':data(dialog)');` is with this `$("#test").data("dialog", "anything");`