# Callback before calendar view is changed

Tags: fullcalendar

I added bootstrap popovers to the calendar events which open on click:

```coffee
eventClick: (event, jsEvent, view) ->
  if event.ajaxUrl?
    elem = jQuery(@)
    elem.popover('destroy')

    jQuery.ajax({url: event.ajaxUrl})
    .done (result) ->
      elem.popover(
        placement: 'top'
        html: true
        trigger: 'manual'
        title: moment(event.start).format('dddd, DD. MMMM YYYY - HH:mm')
        content: result
        container: 'body')

      elem.popover('show')
```

My problem is, that these popovers stay open when I change the calendar view (e.g. change the month or to week/day layout). As the popovers are bound to the `.fc-event` divs/spans within the calendar, I need to access these DOM elements to run `.popover('destroy')`.

Whenever a fullCalendar view is changed, the old DOM-Elements are replaced with the ones for the new view, so I would have to access them before the view is actually changed. Unfortunately there are only callbacks for event loading (`loading` which happens after the view is changed) and `viewDisplay` (same, but you get the new view).

To make sure I understood `viewDisplay` correctly, I added a small test to the calendar which always gives me "0" (the data-selector comes from [jquery data selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector))

```coffee
viewDisplay: (view) ->
    alert(jQuery('.fc-event:data(popover)').size())
```

Is there a way to hook into the calendar process everytime the view is to be changed - but before the view is actually changed?

**Edit**

For now I'm simply destroying the popovers once the mouse is moved over any calendar button (as a bind to `click` would be executed after the view change), but this solution is just a workaround

```coffee
jQuery('.fc-button').on 'mouseover', () ->
    jQuery('.fc-event:data(popover)').popover('destroy')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**V3**

I think you are looking for http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/

From doc

> **viewRender**
>
> Triggered when a new date-range is rendered, or when the view type
> switches. function( view, element ) view is the View Object for the
> new view. element is a jQuery element for the container of the new
> view.
>
> This callback will get triggered when the user changes the view, or
> when any of the date navigation methods are called.
>
> This callback will trigger after the view has been fully rendered,
> but, before events have been rendered (see also: eventAfterAllRender).

### UPDATE

V4 renamed from viewRender to datesRender https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/datesRender

V5 renamed from datesRender to datesSet https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet

Comment: I think I looked into `viewRender` and there was a problem with it, but it's quite some time ago. I'll see if it solves it and if so accept your answer.

Comment: in v5 you want https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet

Answer (score 3):

In V4, viewRender was deprecated, check out the release notes, now they have:

"viewSkeletonRender" callback which is triggered when the new view is mounted, it receives a view object containing a lot of good stuff in it.

"viewSkeletonDestroy" callback which is triggered right before the old view is about to get unmounted.

--

Alternatively, thought may not answer the question directly, you can use the "datesRender" callback. I needed was to run a function when previous, next, or the view changed. (I had to compute the total number of hours of an event type based on the date range and the views)