# How to select elements based on .data({key: value})

Tags: jquery, html, properties, selector, element

In HTML I have a div with various data- attribute properties set within a JSON object, e.g.:

```
<div data-layout='{
      "type" : "header",
      "minHeight" :  "10%"
   }'>
   Layout
</div>
```

In code, is it possible to select only elements which have e.g. `data-layout.type==="header"` without using `.each` or a filter function?

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
$('[data-layout]').find('type="header"')
```

Comment: Kinda, you can use *= to see if `"type" : "header"` appears anywhere within the value of the attribute, however it would be far less prone to issues if you just use .filter.

Comment: I think this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector

Comment: If the data-* attribute is set as simple ("key", "value") I can use attribute selector such as '[key="value"]'. My question is if I can do something similar to select the property of a JSON object as shown in my example, or is .filter the only way. data-layout is not set to a single (string) value but a JSON object. I'm needing to select elements with data-layout attributes having certain properties set to a specific value.

Comment: Thanks uross, only saw your comment after mine. This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: No problem, I am glad I could help. I have added this in answer, so you can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2895933/1185123) answer, you can use pattern described below:

```
:data( {namespace} [{operator} {check}]  )
```

"operator" and "check" are optional. So, if you only have :data(a.b.c) it will simply check for the truthiness of a.b.c.

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2895933/1185123).

Comment: Thanks. The answer provided by Austin also works as long as "header" is not used elsewhere in the data-layout attribute object, but I'm specifically needing to find elements with (e.g.) someAttrProp===someValue.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not use header anywhere else in the data-layout attribute you can use the [attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector like this:

```
$('*[data-layout *="header"]')
```