# data attribute added trough jquery is not being available to select the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code.

```
<ul>
    <li  data-details="li1">first</li>
    <li  >second</li>
</ul>
```

Notice that for the first element i have add `data-details`  attribute with a value.
For the 2nd `li` element i'm adding the same using jquery. Here is my JavaScript code.

```
$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                      $("ul li:nth-child(2)").data("details","li2");
                      console.log($("ul li:nth-child(2)").data()); //data can be verified using this
                      alert($("ul li[data-details=li1]").length); //resulting in alert 1
                      alert($("ul li[data-details=li2]").length); //resulting in alert 0
                  });
```

The data is added we can verify by checking the console. However i'm not able to select the element based on value of `data-details`  which is being added by jquery. Why is it happening so ?

and Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zTsS4/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Data vs Attr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting items with `.data()` **does not** set attributes. If you set the attribute in the HTML or use something like `.attr()`, you can use the **attribute** selector. If you need to find elements that have their `.data()` set, you need to use `.filter()`:

```
var el = $("selector").filter(function () {
    return typeof $(this).data("whatever") !== undefined;
});
console.log(el.length);
```

Note that this isn't the same behavior in the opposite way. When you set an attribute in the HTML or with `.attr()`, any `data-*` attribute will automatically be put into `.data()` by jQuery.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zTsS4/2/

Note how in the demo, the attribute is set in the HTML for one `<li>`, and the other is set with `.data()`. Then the `.filter()` finds both.