# jQuery select all elements except this

Tags: jquery

I want to select all elements on a page and add a class to them. But two of them shouldn't get this class.

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-show-link]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('[data-show-id]').toggle();
    $('*').not($this).not('[data-show-id]').toggleClass('get-opacity'); // ?
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ynts/8hLQG/

Comment: what's the question / problem?

Comment: `$("*")` matches *all* elements, including containers (e.g. the `<body>` element). Opacity cascades down to descendant elements whether or not they expose the `get-opacity` class. You have to refine your first selector.

Comment: very dangerous to use `$('*')` this way, its performance is also bad. So narrow down the context by `$('.wrap *')` instead.

Comment: By far **not** the best solution: `$('*').not('body,html').not($(this)).not('[data-show-id]').toggleClass('get-opacity');` but a *quick and dirty* one. – http://jsfiddle.net/8hLQG/3/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector  , go through this tutorial ...

Comment: @ynt you can update as suggested in the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23931163/1059101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
$('*')
```

to this:

```
$('.wrap').children()
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8hLQG/11/)

Comment: here you are http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/8hLQG/5/ , this wil make the whole `.wrap` affected by opacity.

Comment: @KingKing oh yeah! Just updated the answer and added a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("p").not("[data-show-id]").toggleClass('get-opacity');
```

[JSFIDDLE : Isn't this you're looking for ?](http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub/8hLQG/8/)

Comment: You are right, your solution works with my JSfiddle example. However, that's not the complete solution I'm looking for. My example is a just simplified version of a whole page. In fact, I want to add class to all page elements, not only `p`.