# How to .append to data-reactid

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs

I need to know how to .append a data-reactid being outputted by a Wordpress plugin application. The example below shows the code that is successfully appending to a div with the id of #div1. This is working great.

How do I perform the same function but append to a specific data-reactid?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('#div1').append('<div>Some HTML</div>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery data selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector)

Comment: why would you want to do this? There is probably a more predictable way to accomplish what you need. data-reactid is not used in modern React, so even if it was possible to use it as a jQuery selector (which I dont think it is) theres a large change the person maintaining that app will update their react version and you would lose access to that attribute entirely

Comment: Robbie! Thank you so much for your response. I would love to do this in the easiest most "right" way possible. With the code I'm using above, I simply cannot get it to append to a div that is rendered by React. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I understand that the app developer could change his react scheme, but I do know for sure that the class of the div that i want to append (shove content after) will not change.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`$('[data-reactid="YOUR_REACT_ID"]').append('<div>Some html</div>');`