# Select element by data defined with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select element by data attribute defined with jquery (it's not visible in DOM), therefore I cannot use  `$('.foo:data(id)')`

example: if user clicks element I add data property to it as following

```
$(this).data('id', '1');
```

now I would like to find element which has 
`data-id == 1`

how can I select this element by data-id?

Comment: `$('.foo').filter(function(){ $(this).data('id') == 1; })`

Comment: @Wimanicesir The question you linked is selecting by data attribute defined in DOM, I'm dealing with data defined in jQuery.

Comment: @Satpal - the linked question isn't reflecting, that the data attribute isn't present in the dom, so this isn't a duplicate for the linked quesiton

Comment: @Philipp, There is couple of answer which clearly suggest `.filter()` i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41061135 thus I believe its a duplicate and also I didn't answered it although tried to nudge OP in correct direction via comment

Comment: @Satpal That's true, but the question isn't about that, as you can see in the first 9 answers

Comment: @Philipp, Be happy revoked my dupe hammer

Comment: @Satpal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery data selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891452/jquery-data-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()`

```
$('.foo').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('id') === `1`
}).doSomething()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the attribute selector `[attribute=...]`.

In your case, this would be

```
$('[data-id=1]')
```

But keep in mind, if you change the data of an element with `.data()`, the change isn't reflected in the dom attribute, so you can't use this (or additionally change the dom attribute).

The other way would be to select every candidate and then filter for each element, which has a matching data value.

```
$('.foo').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('id') == 1;
});
```

Comment: Your suggestion works with DOM, but jQuery data is not manipulating DOM data, therefore your answer is invalid